# Which characters are known to have received power from god?

Tags: one-punch-man

As far as I know, Homeless Emperor is the first character to be known to receive power from god. I believe also Psychos-Orochi fusion received also power from god, didnt they? And now we find

> Garou is now receiving extra power from god to fight Saitama

How about other characters, such that character Saitama defeated early in the manga, who created energy spheres like Homeless Emperor?

Which characters are known to have received power from god?